# Why does calling a method on a dereferenced trait object or slice compile?

Tags: rust, traits, dereference

Given the following code:

```
trait Function {
    fn filter (&self);
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Kidney {}

impl Function for Kidney {
    fn filter (&self)  {
        println!("filtered");
    }  
}

fn main() {
    let k = Kidney {};
    let f: &Function = &k;
    //let k1 = (*f);   //--> This gives a "size not satisfied" error
    (*f).filter();     //--> Works; what exactly happens here?
}
```

I am not sure why it compiles. I was expecting the last statement to fail. I guess I have overlooked some fundamentals while learning Rust, as I am failing to understand why dereferencing a trait (that lives behind a pointer) should compile.

Is this issue similar to the following case?

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
//let s: &[i32] = *v;
println!("{}", (*v)[0]);
```

`*v` gives a slice, but a slice is unsized, so again it is not clear to me how this compiles. If I uncomment the second statement I get

```
   |     let s:&[i32]= *v;
   |                   ^^
   |                   |
   |                   expected &[i32], found slice
   |                   help: consider borrowing here: `&*v`
   |
   = note: expected type `&[i32]`
              found type `[{integer}]`
```

Does `expected type &[i32]` mean "expected a reference of slice"?

Comment: `&[T]` is a slice; `[T]` is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereferencing a trait object is no problem. In fact, it must be dereferenced at some point, otherwise it would be quite useless.

`let k1 = (*f);` fails not because of dereferencing but because you try to put the raw trait object on the stack (this is where local variables live). Values on the stack must have a size known at compile time, which is not the case for trait objects because any type could implement the trait.

Here is an example where a structs with different sizes implement the trait:

```
trait Function {
    fn filter (&self);
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Kidney {}

impl Function for Kidney {
    fn filter (&self)  {
        println!("filtered");
    }  
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Liver {
    size: f32
}

impl Function for Liver {
    fn filter (&self)  {
        println!("filtered too!");
    }  
}

fn main() {
    let k = Kidney {};
    let l = Liver {size: 1.0};

    let f: &Function;
    if true {
        f = &k;
    } else {
        f = &l;
    }

    // Now what is the size of *f - Kidney (0 bytes) or Liver (4 bytes)?
}
```

`(*f).filter();` works because the temporarily dereferenced object is not put on the stack. In fact, this is the same as `f.filter()`. Rust automatically applies as many dereferences as required to get to an actual object. This is documented [in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html#deref-and-method-calls).

What happens in the second case is that [`Vec` implements `Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Deref) to slices, so it gets all methods implemented for slices for free. `*v` gives you a dereferenced slice, which you assign to a slice. This is an obvious type error.

Comment: (also @ljedrz)  Thanks! if `self` is received by value and I do `f.filter()`, it gives 2 errors .First, `cannot move a value of type Function: the size of Function cannot be statically determined` and Second, `cannot move out of borrowed content`. Second error is obvious. First one I can't fully understand why it is complaining about size of `Function` and not size of `self` . Could you please elaborate and why it (i.e `f.filter()`) works fine with receiver `self ` as a reference.

Comment: @soupybionics Although this is more or less a different question, the same answer applies. If you have `fn filter(self)` all the compiler knows is that the type `Self` implements `Function`. It does not know the size of `self` because any type could be hiding behind in `f: &Function`. If you try `k.filter()` instead it should work because the size of `k: Kidney` is known at compile time.

Comment: Or simply put, moving a value into another variable such as `let k1 = (*f)` and moving it as argument into a function is basically the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the MIR produced by the first piece of code, `(*f).filter()` is equivalent to `f.filter()`; it appears that the compiler is aware that since `filter` is a method on `&self`, dereferencing it doesn't serve any purpose and is omitted altogether.

The second case, however, is different, because dereferencing the slice introduces bounds-checking code. In my opinion the compiler should also be able to tell that this operation (dereferencing) doesn't introduce any meaningful changes (and/or that there won't be an out-of-bounds error) and treat it as regular slice indexing, but there might be some reason behind this.